# UIDatePicker Not working In Mac Catalyst (Xcode 11 Beta 5)

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, xcode11, mac-catalyst, uikitformac

We are converting our iOS app to Mac Catalyst compatible using Swift in Xcode 11 beta 5.

We have facing issue that default DatePicker not shown in window.

I am trying this solution for mac and it will add date picker in view but I want another proper solution. Any other suggestion?

```
func datepickerWillLoad() {
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    self.datePicker.maximumDate = Date()
    self.datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.Theme.lightBackground
    self.datePicker.setValue(UIColor.Theme.whiteColor, forKeyPath: "textColor")
    self.datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangedDatePickerValue), for: .valueChanged)
    
    //if user open picker and without change click on done
    self.dateOfBirthTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangedDatePickerValue), for: .editingDidEnd)
    
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 200 , width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
        self.view.addSubview(datePicker)
    #else
        self.dateOfBirthTextField.inputView = datePicker
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Is this now working for you? I'm able to get a date picker working.

Comment: Ok i will check for the same... Thank you.

Comment: I have the same setup and have not been able to solve this. Do you have a solution?

Comment: I have done same as above, i did't try any another solution

Comment: @HardikThakkar are you able to see the UIDatePicker on MacOS 10.15.4? In previous MacOS there used to be a normal iOS UIDatePicker which I added to the table view cell. Now, instead of iOS picker I see a MacOS native date picker (calendar like).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the cause of the problem is that the UIDatePicker has been redesigned to a **compact** controller instead of iOS typical **wheel** (probably since Mac Catalyst 13.4+). Therefore, the color scheme could no longer be applied to the not existing wheel with the setValue-function and causes an error.

So I tried to get the wheel mode back to my UIDatePicker. Therefore, I added the following line to my UIDatePicker, which solved the issue for me:

```
if #available(macCatalyst 13.4, *) {
    myDatePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    myDatePicker.datePickerMode = .date
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

For earlier versions I hadn't this problem before, so I am hopefully fine with the solution, but please comment if you are facing the problem also with earlier versions, so I can adapt my code! :-)

**Note**: I noticed that the datePickerMode is set to default mode after changing the preferredDatePickerStyle, so make sure that you force the datePickerMode afterwards!

Comment: This is not working for me. Not even, compact, inline date picker works..it works for my iOS devices any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I set the datepicker text color with
       self.datePicker.setValue(UIColor.Theme.whiteColor, forKeyPath: "textColor")
then this caused the app to crash when loading the view.  Try removing that line of code and it should work with mac catalyst.